# How to read a text file and append the content to it from a Jenkins pipeline job?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have tried the examples from both the links mentioned below. But, I continuously get an error when reading a file content. Anyone please help me to achieve my target.

*Referred links:*

```
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_file_io.htm

http://grails.asia/groovy-file-examples
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Plz share error log

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I found.

```
writeFile file: env.WORKSPACE+"/usefulfile.txt", text: "Apple will be in 1st line"

def readContent = readFile env.WORKSPACE+"/usefulfile.txt"

writeFile file: env.WORKSPACE+"/usefulfile.txt", text: readContent +"\r\nOrange will be in 2nd line"
```